# Drush only partially working in both VM (Ubuntu) and host OS (Mac OS X 10.10)

Tags: 7, features, drush

I am currently running on a MacBook Pro with OS X 10.10 (Yosemite). That is the host machine and OS. I am using a synced folder between the host and my VM, which is running Laravel's Homestead VM (Ubuntu instance).

The project is a Drupal 7 project and I am running the latest version of Drush installed both on Mac OS X (via homebrew) and within the VM (I can't remember how I ended up installing it there). Very new setup, had the machine for a week and a half. Setup this way for maybe a week.

I am able to access and load the site just fine from the VM in my browser. It works great there. But, when I go to use drush against it (both in the VM and in Mac OS) it doesn't seem to give me most of the options.

Within the VM (ssh'ed in) I run "drush pml". Below is the message I get.

```
Command pm-list needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run this command.                     [error]
The drush command 'pml' could not be executed.
```

I get the same message in Mac OS X. I am running the command from the docroot folder where drupal is installed. Not sure why this is. I could see it happening in the host OS. But it SHOULD be working within the VM that is running it and has the DB installed.

I haven't used Drush or Drupal for 2 years. So I probably forgot an obvious config or something. Please help me out here.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are in docroot then the most likely cause is multiple site definitions which mean drush can't tell which is active. You may need to supply the -l or --url parameter to dismbiguate if that is the case. Alternatively have you tried running from the folder where the settings.php is stored?

Comment: I had not tried running from that folder. I actually forgot that this was essentially setup as a multi-site. Had to configure the drushrc file for it with the URL/site-alias to fix it. If you put that in as an answer I will accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in docroot then the most likely cause is multiple site definitions which mean drush can't tell which is active. You may need to supply the -l or --url parameter to disambiguate if that is the case.

In your [drushrc](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drush-ops/drush/master/examples/example.drushrc.php) file you can set up parameters so as to avoid having to keep supplying the parameter explicitly.